# SplitFile gives casting error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have placed a mp4 file on hdfs and trying to analyze it directly i have a class name as `VideoRecordReader` in which it gives the casting error. Below is the description of Error.

> You have loaded library /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 which
>   might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack
>   guard now. attempt_201607261400_0011_m_000000_1: It's highly
>   recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or
>   link it with '-z noexecstack'. 16/07/26 17:32:27 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201607261400_0011_m_000000_2,
>   Status : FAILED java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit    at
>   com.finalyearproject.VideoRecordReader.initialize(VideoRecordReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:521)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

Here is the code of SplitFile.

```
public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();

        start = 0;
        end = 1; 

        final Path file = split.getPath();
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());
        filename = split.getPath().getName();
        byte [] b = new byte[fileIn.available()];
        fileIn.readFully(b);
        video = new VideoObject(b);
    }
```

kindly help me  thank u best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely you're mixing the `mapred` and `mapreduce` APIs together.

Its complaining that you're trying to cast `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit` to `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit`.

You need to make sure that you generally dont mix imports between the two APIs.

So check if the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit` has been imported and change it to `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit`.